# iOS 8 simulator not working with Xcode 8

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, ios8.1

My client has a bug on an iPad Air with iOS 8.1
I can't reproduce this bug and I don't have a device under iOS 8.1.

So I tried to wanted to try with the simulator. I can download the iOS simulator 8.1 from the Preferences, but I'm unable to see it in the list when I try to run my application (even on Simulator > Hardware > device, I only have iOS 9 and 10). 
I'm using Xcode 8.3.2 (the latest).

How can I test my app on previous iOS versions ?

Thanks !

Julian

Comment: What's the base target that you've set for your project on your xcode?

Comment: Sorry, my deployment target is set to 8.0. The minimum possible

Comment: ok I restarted my computer and now it works ....

Comment: Cool... Good to hear